# Q_ENUMS with BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I'm working on a project which has enum definitions with `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM` like:

```
BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START(myEnum)
{
    A = 0,
    B
};
BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END;
```

Now i want to register this enum in QT using `Q_ENUMS` and define `Q_PROPERTY` with it, like:

`Q_ENUMS(myEnum)`

`Q_PROPERTY(myEnum myEnumVar READ getMyEnumVar WRITE setMyEnumVar)`

This is not working, i tried adding `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM()` macro on `Q_ENUMS` and `Q_PROPERTY` definition but it didn't help either.

What is the proper way of registering `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM` enums with `Q_ENUMS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_*` are just declaring struct:

```
# define BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_START(name) struct name { enum enum_t
# define BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_END };
# define BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM(name) name::enum_t
```

So your enum actually is `name::enum_t`.
Also the Qt-documentation says following about `Q_ENUMS`:

> If you want to register an enum that is declared in another class, the
>   enum must be fully qualified with the name of the class defining it.
>   In addition, **the class defining the enum has to inherit QObject** as
>   well as declare the enum using Q_ENUMS().

I think it's impossible to use `BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM_*` with `Q_ENUMS`, cause it generates struct that doesn't inherit `QObject`.

Comment: I already tried it but it didn't work. The thing is in the moc generated cpp file i can see that all enum values are proessed and included to the moc_*.cpp file, however i can not see the enum values defined with BOOST_SCOPED_ENUM macro in moc generated cpp file, I think the problem is about moc generator of qt. By the way I am using QT 5.0.2.

Comment: @ufuk I had read the documentation more deeply. Check the updated answer please.

Comment: So it explaines the situation, Thanks.